# How do you get a gimp plugin/script to appear in menu

Tags: gimp

I am using Gimp 2.8.16 on Ubuntu

I am following the tutorial [here](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/automating-gimp-scripts/)

I have created the script hello_world.py and saved it to

~/.gimp-2.8/scripts.hello_world.py

I restart Gimp, but there is no sign of the message in any menu.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Python files go to a plug-ins directory, they aren't scripts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Python "scripts" are technically plug-ins, not scripts, so they got in the "plug-ins" subdirectory.
- On Linux, they should have the executable flag set
- They have to "register" with Gimp (they make one or more calls to the register(...) functions

Typical debug technique:

- Add a bunch of `print` statements, typically:

  - a wide `print '*********************'` at the top to make the print out up easy to spot)
  - one before the calls to register()
  - one after
- Start Gimp in a terminal, you should normally see the output of your prints. If any is missing, look for error messages. Syntax errors prevent the whole script from running, you won't even see your first line.
- Before even running the script from Gimp, try `python the_script.py` in a terminal to catch the biggest mistakes (parentheses mismatch, etc...). When the output is `ImportError: No module named gimpfu` the script is good enough to try in Gimp (`gimpfu` is only defined when run from Gimp)

Comment: Thanks. Wrong directory and executable not set :(

Comment: Please consider accepting the answer then.